# Check duplication within the same MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
id  district    icnum
 1     10       111
 2     10       112
 3     10       113
 4     10       114
 5     10       111
 6     20       115
 7     20       116
 8     20       117
 9     20       111
10     20       111
11     30       118
12     30       119
13     30       111
14     30       111
15     30       120
```

I have the above sample table. I want to create a mysql query to check duplication of 'icnum', a summary/count and also a list of the duplication. What

I want is:

How many 'icnum' within district '10' is found in district '20'.
How many 'icnum' within district '10' is found in district '30'.
How many 'icnum' within district '20' is found in district '30'.

I've tried several queries found in stackoverflow but it doesn't give me the result I want. I'm a newbie in complex sql query.

So should I execute the query separately for every district to get the result. Please masters of MySQL in stackoverflow, help me with this. Tq.

Below is the sample output that i want:

```
district    district    count(*)
   10         20          2
   10         30          2
   20         30          2
```

Comment: This isn't a complex query. See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: huhu, then i guess i'm a total nobbs...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a self-join:

```
select t1.district, t2.district, count(distinct t1.icnum)
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.icnum = t2.icnum and t1.district < t2.district
group by t1.district, t2.district;
```

Notes:

- If you don't have duplicates, then use `count(*)` instead of `count(*)`.
- This will not return pairs that have nothing in common (although that could be fixed).

Comment: using my sample data, which is about the same i post here, the result is seemed doubled, meaning got 1 duplication of icnum of district 10 in district 20, but it displayed 2, got 3 duplication of icnum of district 20 in district 30 but it displayed 6..I guess it's because of the < operator..

Comment: @Shahril . . . No.  The `<` should reduce the number of rows being returned by a factor of 2.  It should not double anything.

Comment: The original answer said to use `count(distinct)` if you have duplicates.  Because you do, I made that the first answer.

Comment: I use the query on my real table which has about 2.5 million rows. I execute the query and It's been almost 15 minutes and the query is still running. Is it normal?

Comment: @Shahril . . . It depends how large your districts are.  You might have some districts that have a lot of `icnum`s -- you might want to filter these out.